# I Can not access my xampp sever for others project instead of laravel project....!

Tags: php, laravel-4, xampp

I am learning laravel framework. I have installed it on virtually and configured this C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts windows system file. After changing this file Laravel projects working nicely but I am facing problem with other projects, they are not working and I got this error message something like

"Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

and I have configured virtual host on the system file like this

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

    127.0.0.1       laravel.test1
```

Is there anyone who face this problem or please suggest me something from where I can solve this problem. Or is there any terrible mistake I have done here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit also your httpd-vhosts file in yourDrive:\xampp\apache\conf\extra
  and for each domain you want to have add

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "yourDrive:\xampp\htdocs\temp"
  ServerName www.temp.dev
  ServerAlias www.temp.dev
  ErrorLog "yourDrive:/xampp/htdocs/temp/error.log"
 <Directory "yourDrive:/xampp/htdocs/temp">
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

Comment: @Md.JahedulHoque Np. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct

Comment: I tried to mark the ans correct but as I am new in stackoverflow and for marking a ans as correct I must need 15 reputation for it. I will do it whenever my reputation increase 15. Thanks :)